# I couldn't embed pdf file in ie8

Tags: pdf, internet-explorer-8, embed

I tried to embed a pdf file on my web application for user to preview. the  tag works fine with firefox but when it comes to ie8 it doesn't work at all. I tried  tag it doesn't.
I tried , the browser hung.  I tried all sorts of jquery lib available still it didn't work.  Google doc viewer and zoho pdf viewer don't work for me as my file is not online.   I have exhausted my resouces.

Has anyone come across this problem before? if so would you like to share it with?  Thank you so much.

Comment: Pls update your question with the code that you used. Where is the PDF stored? Client or server side? If the PDF is stored server side and it is not online, how did you make it work with other browsers? If the PDF is client side, then why use a web app to preview?

Comment: Does your ie8 display PDFs when opened manually? If not, you will need a helper for your ie8 to display PDF, such as Adobe Reader.